# What can I do with maas without juju

Tags: server, maas

I have short questions about MaaS.

1. Is this MaaS like beowulf cluster? Is it provides more power with nodes?
2. What can I do with MaaS without Juju? Can I use like desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAAS (Metal as a Service) is a hardware provisioning layer, not a complete cluster-like OS. The purpose of MAAS is simply to enable the user to bring up a collection of hardware nodes and then deploy whatever services they need on top.
So MAAS will

1. Discover available nodes on the network.
2. Commission them with your choice of ubuntu server image.
3. Manage and allocate the nodes into groups which  you can then target with other services.

So, yes, you CAN use MAAS without juju if you just need to bring up a lot of hardware and install Ubuntu Server images on it. Juju makes it easier to deploy other services such as databases, web servers or even a full OpenStack.

For more explanation of MAAS, you should check out [the MAAS documentation](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/orientation.html)